# Replace special character on text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code snippet :

```
<div class="caption" >
<span class="id">
<span class="eccc-1200">F
<span class="small-caps">I</span>
<span class="small-caps">G</span>
<span class="small-caps">U</span>
<span class="small-caps">R</span>
<span class="small-caps">E</span>
</span>&#x00A0;1.1: </span>
<span class="content">Norme d&#8217;un vecteur</span></div>
```

and I would like to remove the ":" character on `</span>&#x00A0;1.1: </span>` line, i.e to get `</span>&#x00A0;1.1 </span>` .

I tried :

```
$('div.caption span.id').text().replace(':','')
```

but it doesn't seem to work, I don't know why ...

If someone could see what's wrong,

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have one too many </span> closing tags

Comment: ^ On `&#x00A0;1.1: </span>`: extra closing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the jQuery method .text() will return the content in a text format, and then you're using .replace(...) to replace the content and after that you aren't doing anything with the result of the replace method, you can do something like:

```
var result = $('div.caption span.id').text().replace(':','')
$('div.caption span.id').text( result )
```

Comment: jQuery selector is a bit expensive to run. Better use a variable to hold it.

Comment: Yes you are completely correct, I thought I wouldn't post unnecessary code, that was not a part of the issue in the original code.

Comment: thanks, I thought text().replace(':','') modified directly  the content and setted the new content.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    var span = $('div.caption span.id')
    span.text(span.text().replace(':', ''))
```

Comment: jQuery selector is a bit expensive to run. Better use a variable to hold it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('div.caption span.id').text($('div.caption span.id').text().replace(/:/g, ''))
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="caption">
        <span class="id">
            <span class="eccc-1200">F
                <span class="small-caps">I</span>
                <span class="small-caps">G</span>
                <span class="small-caps">U</span>
                <span class="small-caps">R</span>
                <span class="small-caps">E</span>
            </span>
            &#x00A0;1.1: 

        </span>
        <span class="content">Norme d&#8217;un vecteur</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this work?

```
var $element = $('div.caption span.id')
$element.html($element.html().replace(':',''))
```

if you want every : replaced

```
.replace(/:/g,'');
```

Also, change to html() if you want to keep the spans and rest of the markup. If you just want the text then stay with text().

Comment: Why are you switching to `.html()` after replaced text? This will introduce a XSS possibility

Comment: Updated original answer to include reply to this comment. Original post has some extra html markup. If you want to keep those you have to switch. Im assuming since spans have classes that author would like to keep those classes and spans